# In shake-build, how to run a command with a pipe in it?

Tags: shake-build-system

I can't seem to get the following to work in `shake`:

```hs
cmd_ (AddEnv "PGPASSWORD" "REDACTED") "bzcat /tmp/db.sql.bz2 | psql -U pguser -h localhost dbname"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Shake, the `cmd` function and variants spawn processes directly by default. The pipe syntax is only available as part of the OS's shell functionality. To ask Shake to spawn things using the shell add the argument `Shell`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
Stdout pipe <- cmd (AddEnv "PGPASSWORD" "REDACTED") "bzcat /tmp/db.sql.bz2"
cmd_ "psql -U pguser -h localhost dbname" (Stdin pipe)
```